# How to stream live, auto-updating charts of my ML model to my website?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, next.js, pytorch, cloud

So I'm trying to create a website which displays live and automatically updating graphs using my deep learning model.

I'm trying to establish a workflow as follows:
-use api to get daily new stock data
-have my model automatically train on new data (in cloud)
-update graph on website with new data

There's a website called finbrain.tech and I am trying to implement something like this.

For reference, I am building my website with NextJs, and I am using Python for the deep learning side of things.

Can someone please point me in the right direction to go about establishing such a workflow??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one idea for a workflow: Your application can schedule a task to call the API daily (perhaps with https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/) and upload the data to the ML platform. Then, take the output and save it in cloud storage or a cloud database, and your website can read it from there to produce the graph.